# Is there any way to find place where NGXS action was dispatched?

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs

I am starting to use NGXS and maybe I misunderstand something, but I cannot find an easy way to locate the component where the action was dispatched... For example, without NGXS If some error was thrown, I can use console traces to locale a chain of functions that led to this, not only the last one. But with NGXS I can trace only the action itself that causes the exception, but how to find a specific place in code that dispatched this errored action?

Answer (score 0):

As a debug mode aid, you can add another property to your action ( you can name it caller ), then in the different dispatching components you can fill it in with the component name, then when the action throws an error you should have the component name in the action log. Don't forget to remove it before deploying to production.